# Resolving DNSLookupFailedError for Python web proxy

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns

My code is as follows:

https://github.com/T145/tphroxy/blob/master/mirror.py

https://github.com/T145/tphroxy/blob/master/transform_content.py

And when going to certain websites I get errors along these lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " ... /mirror.py", line 108, in fetch_and_store
    response = urlfetch.fetch(mirrored_url)
  File " ... /google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 293, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File " ... /google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File " ... /python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 449, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DNSLookupFailedError('DNS lookup failed for URL: ' + url)
DNSLookupFailedError: DNS lookup failed for URL: http://public/images/v6/btn_arrow_down_padded_white.png
```

My guess is that specific asset url patterns aren't being matched and sent through the proxy properly, i.e. `transform_content` is missing a pattern. Any help to solving this problem is greatly appreciated! I'm open to using any alternative libraries if needed.

[DEMO](https://tphroxy.appspot.com/)

**EDIT**

I've added a [test suite](https://github.com/T145/tphroxy/blob/master/transform_content_test.py) for `transform_content`, and I'm certain the primary problems are with my regex expressions from its results. Run it w/ `py transform_content_test.py` if you're on Windows to get the results.

Comment: Just from some surface testing over at https://regex101.com/, `BASE_RELATIVE_URL_REGEX` fails when testing `slashdot.org`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DNS lookup failed for URL: http://public/...` Note the missing domain (host) portion in the URL, the `public` string will be parsed as the domain, which is invalid, causing the error you see.

The URL should be something like `http://<valid_domain>/public/...`, so check your code building that URL.

You're doing quite a few string ops on the URLs, check that all your possible code paths operate properly, my guess is that some are not doing what you're expecting them to.

Comment: Based on your observation, I'd say the problem would lie around the MirrorHandler, since the error occurs when I pass a URL into `fetch_and_store`. So that means I must be doing something wrong around here: https://github.com/T145/tphroxy/blob/master/mirror.py#L179. See anything noteworthy?

Comment: Yep, through there. The 'r"/"' potentially returned by `BaseHandler.get_relative_url()` would definitely not have a host part, for example. Add a few more debug statements here and there and repro - it should not be a big deal finding out where the issue is.

Comment: The problem is w/ `base_url`; in the logging from my post example I get that the base URL equals `public`, which it shouldn't. Could the regex I apply to it when declaring `app` at the bottom of the source file be the issue?

Comment: Possibly. The output of your 2nd `logging.debug()` in `MirrorHandler.get()` in the logs should tell.

Comment: It does, and confirms the info previously stated. I deleted all of the memcaching code, and got a new error: `File " ... /mirror.py", line 168, in get
    for (key, value) in content.headers.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'headers'`. This error does not affect visual output. The new code is on GH.

Comment: `content` is `None`, you should check for that.

Comment: Ik it is. My question is why is it null? Why did this just start happening after removing the caching functionality?